# Get Date from String

Tags: c#, string, datetime

Lets say I have one of following strings:

```
"Hello, I'm a String... This is a Stackoverflowquestion!! Here is a Date: 16.03.2013, 02:35 and yeah, plain text blah blah..-."

"This the other string! :) 22.11.2012. Its a Date you see"

"Here we have 2 Dates, 23.12.2012 and 14.07.2011"
```

What would be the best and fastest way to get these dates from the string (in `DateTime`)?

(Only First occured Date in String)

Desirable Returns:

```
String 1: 16.03.2013 (as a DateTime)
String 2: 22.11.2012 ("           ")
String 3: 23.12.2012 ("           ")
```

So I would call a method something like:

```
DateTime date1 = GetFirstDateFromString(string1);
```

Comment: This seems to be a problem to solve with Regular Expression!

Comment: If those are culture-specific formats for the dates, you can extract the date format and use a regular expression to search the string.

Comment: They are yes. They are always in such a Format

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This will extract, parse and print all dates in the input text:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\b\d{2}\.\d{2}.\d{4}\b");
foreach(Match m in regex.Matches(inputText))
{
    DateTime dt;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(m.Value, "dd.MM.yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
        Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString());
}
```

Now, if you just want the first date, you can do that:

```
static DateTime? GetFirstDateFromString(string inputText)
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"\b\d{2}\.\d{2}.\d{4}\b");
    foreach(Match m in regex.Matches(inputText))
    {
        DateTime dt;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(m.Value, "dd.MM.yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
            return dt;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note that the method returns a nullable `DateTime`, so that it can return null when the string contains no date.

Comment: This will fall over on, for example `"58.99.2013"`.

Comment: @MartinMulder, no it won't; it will just skip it and process the next match

Comment: Thanks for the solution

Comment: Mother of regex ^_^

Comment: @ThomasLevesque, I tried this solution for dd-MMM-yyyy format with modification in regex but it's not working for me. Can you please help me to get date from below string
"8 Week Group Coaching - 07-Nov-2021 to 31-Dec-2021 ( 05:00:00 AM to 06:00:00 AM )"

Comment: @ManishNayak it should work with this regex: `@"\b\d{2}-[A-Za-z]{3}-\d{4}\b"`
Also, you should probably use the invariant or en-US culture as the `provider` parameter.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque thanks for your help, @"\b\d{2}-[A-Za-z]{3}-\d{4}\b" worked for me :)

Answer (score 7):

If your dates are always in that format, you could try using a regex to grab the date string and then use `DateTime.ParseExact` to get the result you want:

```
public DateTime? GetFirstDateFromString(string input)
{
    DateTime d;

    // Exclude strings with no matching substring
    foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, @"[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}"))
    {
        // Exclude matching substrings which aren't valid DateTimes
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(match.Value, "dd.MM.yyyy", null, 
            DateTimeStyles.None, out d))
        {
            return d;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @JimMischel Oops! Had one on the clipboard but forgot to paste it in! Done.

Comment: Will fail, if 58.99.2013 is in the string before an actual date.

Comment: Here I had some Problems.. u cant return null if return type isn't nullable, second thing is, that the Variable "enUS" no where is defined.. I'd rather use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture , but thanks anyway and +1 for your effort!

Comment: True - I've addressed these issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
   public static DateTime? GetFirstDateFromString(string input);
   {
      string pattern = @"\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}";
      Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
      DateTime result;
      foreach(string value in match.Groups)  
          if (DateTime.TryParseExact(match.Groups[1], "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result)
              return result;
      return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: This will fall over on, for example "58.99.2013"

Comment: Adjusted! It now search for the first matching date/time, otherwise returns null.

Answer (score 1):

For me this code works to get Date from string text contains date.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}");
 foreach (Match m in regex.Matches(line))
 {
  DateTime dt;
  if (DateTime.TryParseExact(m.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
  remittanceDateArr[chequeNo - 1] = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");                                   
  rtbExtract.Text = rtbExtract.Text + remittanceDateArr[chequeNo - 1] + "\n";
                            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method whose parameters are a regular expression to catch the date format and the string that you will be extracting the date from. I believe if you don't have a format that will be used then it won't be possible to extract the date from a series of alphanumeric characters in a string.