# Extract date time from file name with extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I want to extract date from the string.

String : `_21_BT_Txn_Details_1-Aug-2015_1031389ACF6.zip`

How to do it?

Comment: Look for the date in the string & strip the rest.

Comment: Try this: `\d+-\w+-\d+` .. _https://regex101.com/r/lW9yI3/1_

Comment: No, split by `_` and use `DateTime.Parse()` on the elements to check which is a correct date.

Comment: Searched Google for "extract date from string c#" and the first result was [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222693/get-date-from-string)...

Comment: @OzW: That won't help here. The format is different.

Comment: If the OP is ready to do _some_ work, the accepted answer to that question is good enough IMO. It describes the way to pull a portion from a string using regex, then parse it to a Date object with a specific format. The OP will need to figure out the specifics for his case alone, but that's the way to do it if you wanna learn.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\d{1,2}-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d{4}
```

Demo and explanation of regex symbols: https://regex101.com/r/lW9yI3/2

Assumptions:

- Day could be one or two digits
- Year is always four digits
- Standard three-letter abbreviations are use for the month

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code that can extract more than 1 dates inside the string like the one you provided:

```
var txt = "_21_BT_Txn_Details_1-Aug-2015_1031389ACF6.zip";
DateTime dt;
var res = txt.Split('_').Where(p => DateTime.TryParse(p, out dt)).ToList();
```

Or, if you always have the date in the above format (`day-MON-year`), use

```
DateTime.TryParseExact(p, "d-MMM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt)
```

There is no need for a regex here.

[image]